# What is the correct way to send a string using AJAX with Spring and Thymeleaf? Status : 400

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am getting error ""Required UsernameSearch parameter 'username' is not present" when sending data using ajax with Spring and Thymeleaf. My script is as shown below

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#opusername").keyup(function() {
  var username = $('#opusername').text();

          $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "/create/check-username-availability",
            data : {"username" : username},
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000,
            success : function(data) {
              console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            },
            error : function(e) {
              console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            },
            done : function(e) {
              console.log("DONE");
            }
          });
      });
  });
```

My controller has this method which should receive the string and return a value to indicate whether the username is available or not.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create/check-username-availability", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public String checkUsernameAvailability(@RequestParam("username") UsernameSearch username) {
    logger.info("Checking username availability for username = " + username.getUsername());

    return "true";
}
```

This is the object I create which contains the username String. I have done this after following tutorials and answers here but nothing seems to work.

public class UsernameSearch {

```
String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

}

This is the error when debugging

```
error:"Bad Request"
exception:"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"
```

message:"Required UsernameSearch parameter 'username' is not present"
path:"/create/check-username-availability"
status:400
timestamp:1489942516434

I also wanted to ask how to consume the result from the spring method. Is it possible to get a boolean value?

Answer (score 1):

Change @RequestParam to @RequestBody. Request param != body of the request.

The 400 HTTP error means that the the request is malformed. In your case, the controller expects that the url will have a "username" parameter. Therefore you can either change the ajax call, to send the username as the request parameter, i.e. by attaching "?username=fooBar" to the url you're perfoming POST request and change the controller method signature to accept @RequestParam("username") String username, or change the annotation on the controller parameter to @RequestBody, which tells the controller that the data will be sent as an object in the body of the request.

Comment: Thank you. Changing URL works fine as you suggested so I think I will go for that in the meantime. Using @RequestBody gives error "Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')"Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'username': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Answer (score 1):

function ajax:

```
var data = {
    username: $('#opusername').text()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/create/check-username-availability",
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // Note it is important
    success: function (result) {
        // do whatever you want with data
    }
});
```

and in your java method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create/check-username-availability", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String checkUsernameAvailability(@RequestBody UsernameSearch username) {
    logger.info("Checking username availability for username = " + username.getUsername());

    return "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't send your data as string!
Do the following:

```
data : {"username" : username},
```

Comment: Sorry this is one of the things I have been changing to try and make it work. I posted it with JSON.stringify but I have update the question. I get the same error as json

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting caught up with the various levels all labeled as `username`.  As your server is written now, it is expecting a parameter which is identified as `username` to be of type `UsernameSearch` which is an object with a single property of `username`.  To be explicit, you are expecting the sent body (which is an object) to have a property of `username` where the value is an object which also has a property called `username`.  So the server is expecting

```
{
  'username': {
    'username': 'search value'
  }
}
```

What you are sending is an object with a property of 'username' but a value of string:

```
{
  'username': 'search value'
}
```

The answer is to be consistent.  If you think your search criteria will become more than the one field, then update your client, if not, then change the server to accept a string rather than an object.

**Update:**
Also, you have `@RequestParam` but you should use `@RequestBody`.